# Xcode AES encrypt / decrypt - php compatibilty issues

Tags: php, ios, xcode, aes, rijndael

I am trying to encrypt a string in Xcode and decrypt it with PHP or encrypt with PHP and decrypt with Xcode.

So first of all I am trying to get the same `AES encryption` result.

Here is my Xcode file (I've put everything in a single file for simplicity):

```
#import "t.h"
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonCryptor.h>

@interface NSData(AES)
- (NSData*)AES256EncryptWithKey:(NSString*)key;
- (NSData*)AES256DecryptWithKey:(NSString*)key;
@end

@implementation NSData (AES)

- (NSData*)AES256EncryptWithKey:(NSString*)key {
char keyPtr[kCCKeySizeAES256];

[key getCString:keyPtr maxLength:sizeof(keyPtr) encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

NSString *iv = @"1234567812345678";
char ivPtr[kCCKeySizeAES128];

[iv getCString:ivPtr maxLength:sizeof(ivPtr) encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];    

NSUInteger dataLength = [self length];

size_t bufferSize           = dataLength + kCCBlockSizeAES128;
void* buffer                = malloc(bufferSize);

size_t numBytesEncrypted    = 0;
CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt(kCCEncrypt, kCCAlgorithmAES128, NULL,
                                      keyPtr, kCCKeySizeAES256,
                                      ivPtr /* initialization vector (optional) */,
                                      [self bytes], dataLength, /* input */
                                      buffer, bufferSize, /* output */
                                      &numBytesEncrypted);

if (cryptStatus == kCCSuccess)
{
    return [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:numBytesEncrypted];
}

free(buffer); //free the buffer;
return nil;
}

- (NSData*)AES256DecryptWithKey:(NSString*)key {
char keyPtr[kCCKeySizeAES256];  

NSString *iv = @"1234567812345678";
char ivPtr[kCCKeySizeAES128];

[iv getCString:ivPtr maxLength:sizeof(ivPtr) encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];


// fetch key data
[key getCString:keyPtr maxLength:sizeof(keyPtr) encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

NSUInteger dataLength = [self length];

size_t bufferSize           = dataLength + kCCBlockSizeAES128;
void* buffer                = malloc(bufferSize);

size_t numBytesDecrypted    = 0;
CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt(kCCDecrypt, kCCAlgorithmAES128, NULL,
                                      keyPtr, kCCKeySizeAES256,
                                      ivPtr /* initialization vector (optional) */,
                                      [self bytes], dataLength, /* input */
                                      buffer, bufferSize, /* output */
                                      &numBytesDecrypted);

if (cryptStatus == kCCSuccess)
{
    return [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:numBytesDecrypted];
}

free(buffer); //free the buffer;
return nil;
}

@end



@interface t ()
@end

@implementation t

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];


NSString *key = @"12345678123456781234567812345678";

NSData *plaintext =  [[@"aaa0000000000000" dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding] AES256EncryptWithKey: key];

label1.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:plaintext encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];


}

@end
```

And now the PHP code:

```
<?php

$key256 = "12345678123456781234567812345678";
$iv128 = "1234567812345678";
$text = "aaa";

$blocksize = 16;
$len = strlen($text);
$pad = $blocksize - ($len % $blocksize);

$text .= str_repeat("0", $pad);

$cipher = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key256, $text, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv128);

echo $cipher;

?>
```

The Xcode encrypted string and the php encrypted string are different.

PHP: `â5¢Ð[Iüf#hÂ(Æ`

Xcode: `¡#yZPbEs¿D6ñ`

What can I do to make it work? Am I doing something wrong?

I will further explain what the code does and how it is structured so you can easier understand the problem (correct me if I am wrong):

1. Both PHP and Xcode use CBC for AES encryption so I guess there is no problem there.
2. As you can see I am just trying to get the same result - security does not matter here - so I used no padding - the text is exactly 128 bits in length (16 characters).
3. The key is 256 bits (32 characters).
4. The Initialization Vector is 128 bits (16 characters).

Thank you very much.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: The line `- (NSData*)AES256EncryptWithKey:(NSString*)key {` does correctly define the same key as PHP, does it?

Comment: Yes. You can see both keys in my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally got it! (after asking Apple about it)

Apparently getting getCString from NSString is wrong because the routine tries to null terminate the string and a 32-byte buffer is not big enough to terminate a 32-chars string.

The correct way to get the key or IV would be:

```
[key cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

Comment: I am not getting any proper value same as PHP :(

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
[key getCString:keyPtr maxLength:sizeof(keyPtr) encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

to

```
[key getCString:keyPtr maxLength:sizeof(keyPtr) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

I believe this is an encoding issue

Comment: Nope... that was my initial code too... It makes no difference if it is UTF8 or ASCII - the encryption is exactly the same: ¡#yZPbEs¿D6ñ

Answer (score 0):

When using this code from the very beginning of the page, I am able to encrypt only 16 characters of text. Actually I am able to encrypt any size of text, but when I decrypt that encrypted NSData, I get only 16 characters or 128bits.

Does this has something to do with IV? Is this code made to encrypt ONLY 128bits and if I have bigger size of the text, I need to provide (for better security) new IV and encrypt second block?

Comment: Yes the code above was used to only encrypt 16 bytes as a compatibility test between iOS and php. Try to replace the NULL in "CCCrypt(kCCDecrypt, kCCAlgorithmAES128, NULL, ..." with kCCOptionPKCS7Padding. Again - now you will not have the same results with php as php uses a different padding function.

Comment: Ok, great, I was just checking if I implemented this normally. But wait, what does PKCS7 padding has to do with plain text input? Isn't padding only for key - if key is short and then pad it with non zeros?

Comment: No, padding is used for the text. AES 128 only works with blocks of text of 128 bits... So your text must be padded so it can be exactly devided in blocks of 128 bits.

Comment: sorry if I'm bothering now, but this is more learning cryptology than ios programming. Since we specified that keylength is 256bits (32 1byte characters), what is happening with the key if it's shorter or longer than that size?

Comment: AES 128bits works with key lengths of 128 bits and 256 bits (maybe others - never tryed). You are correct, once you decide the key length it must be exactly 128 or 256 bits. However, padding the key to get to the desired size is not a good ideea as it can result in severe security problems. You should salt the key, see more here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)

Comment: Yeah, I'm familiar with that. I was just wondering what is CCCryptor doing here if I give him shorter key. App is encrypting even if I give it 4 characters as key. Is CCCryptor putting zeros after those 4 characters to fill the gap up to 128 or 256 bits?
Thank you for this productive discussion :)

Comment: Yes, if you are using the getCString it tryes to null terminate the string. You should use cStringUsingEncoding.